# what does "it" mean in the following"...in the planned, intentional, reflective manner it proposes?"

Tags: pronouns

The original context is in the last two line.

[image]

> How focused are you on developing career management skills **in the planned, intentional, refective manner** *it* **proposes**?

does it mean developing career management skills, a manner or one of career management skills?

My guess is developing career management skills.

Comment: I'm almost certain that "it" refers to something in a previous sentence, a course, committee, some form or education or standards setting. So we need more context. Please include a link to your source.

Comment: @PeterJennings I upload the full context. You may refer to more clearly hopefully. Appreciate your words.

Comment: "it" there refers to the antecedent: intentional management of work, learning and life.

Comment: 'This model' refers to the career development model described above. 'It' also means the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The antecedent of the singular pronoun "it" is almost certainly not "developing career management skills" or "the planned, intentional, refective manner", since it is unclear how "developing" or a "manner" could "propose" anything. It is also almost certainly not a single "career management skill", since no such skill has been identified.

Because we can't find the antecedent in this sentence, we should look to the previous one, and we find a suitable antecedent in that sentence's subject: "this model". (Kate Bunting noted this in a comment above.) Therefore, the sentence means:

> How focused are you on developing career management skills in the planned, intentional, refective manner [[that]] this model proposes?